# Replacing attributes of raster cells with other raster values?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, conditional

I have two raster layers.  The first is a terrestrial habitat raster that includes an open water value.  The second is a lentic habitat raster.  I would like to "burn in" the lentic habitat raster values to the terrestrial habitat raster anywhere that it overlaps a cell with an open water value.  I am close to completing this with the conditional tool, but all open water cells in the terrestrial raster that are not overlapped by cells in the lentic raster are being replaced by no_data.  I understand why this is happening, but I am having trouble figuring out how to modify my workflow to get this done. Please let me know if you have any suggestions for a modified workflow or a different method.  Here's what I'm currently doing:

```
1. Expand tool on the lentic raster to ensure lentic habitats are at least the width extent of the open water classes
2. Conditional tool with parameters shown in first figure
```

[image]

And below is a snapshot of the output with black cells representing cells that originally had open water values but now have no_value.
[image]

Comment: Just off the top of my head could you not do the reverse? Input conditional raster is your lentic, when true, let it be lentic otherwise habitat layer?

Comment: I thought about this.  However, I want the lentic layer to "clip" to the open water value cells in the terrestrial habitat layer.

Comment: I now have taken care of the "clip" in another step... but, now when I run the Con tool, I'm not sure what conditional to use since technically the empty cells aren't null values, but instead contain nodata.  Therefore, when I run the tool, it does not fill any of the cells other than the lentic.

Comment: Another trick is to convert your nulls into zero values then [ADD](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/plus.htm) the lentic to the habitat layer. If for example your habitat layer have values from 1 to 20 and water happened to be 17 then when you add your lentic layer where lentic cells are say 100 water comes out as 117, you could optionally reclassify that back to 17.